# Convert interlaced(?) video to progressive

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

I have a video with the following details:

```
Format                      : MPEG-TS
File size                   : 6.49 GiB
Duration                    : 1 h 35 min
Overall bit rate mode       : Variable
Overall bit rate            : 9 694 kb/s

Video
ID                          : 512 (0x200)
Menu ID                     : 1 (0x1)
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : High@L4.1
Format settings             : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : Yes
Format settings, Reference  : 3 frames
Codec ID                    : 27
Duration                    : 1 h 35 min
Bit rate                    : 8 827 kb/s
Width                       : 1 920 pixels
Height                      : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate                  : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Standard                    : Component
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : MBAFF
Scan type, store method     : Separated fields
Scan order                  : Top Field First
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.142
Stream size                 : 5.91 GiB (91%)
Color range                 : Limited
Color primaries             : BT.709
Transfer characteristics    : BT.709
Matrix coefficients         : BT.709

Audio
ID                          : 513 (0x201)
Menu ID                     : 1 (0x1)
Format                      : AC-3
Format/Info                 : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name             : Dolby Digital
Codec ID                    : 129
Duration                    : 1 h 35 min
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 384 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 6 channels
Channel layout              : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                  : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 263 MiB (4%)
Service kind                : Complete Main
```

I want to convert (using ffmpeg) from 1080(?) to 720p, the point is, I don't know if it's interlaced or progressive, is the first time I see MBAFF.

Answer (score 1):

> Scan type                   : MBAFF
> Scan type, store method     : Separated fields
> Scan order                  : Top Field First

MBAFF Information can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding

Not sure how did you get such information, MediaInfo? But those Scan information can't be a progressive.

Comment: Yeah, it was through MediaInfo. I managed to convert, used yadif to deinterlace and it worked. Thanks.